# Create a Count Up Timer in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript

Hey, I'm just wondering if someone could tell me, or point me in the right direction, on how to make a count up timer.

I'd like to have it constantly, from the second I put it into place count up saying the seconds, minutes, hours, days, and years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a Javascript CountUp Timer I wrote.](http://praveenlobo.com/blog/javascript-countup-timer/)
It takes a timestamp to start counting the time from, an ID to put the timer, and a message to append to the timer. Please find the demo page link at the bottom of the post there(unable to provide the link here). Demo page has two types of counters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = 1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: how would I use that to count up though?

Comment: @jason: -1: please don't just post a link. At least _say_ something about what's at the link.

Comment: you would change the line
CountStepper = -1;
to 
CountStepper = 1;